# Why does List.Sort that will for sure fail at runtime compiles?

Tags: c#

I was playing around to see what compiler error will I get if I create `List` of objects that do not implement comparison operators and call `.Sort()` . 
I was surprised that it compiled and then crashed at runtime:

```
[System.ArgumentException: At least one object must implement IComparable.]
   at System.Collections.Comparer.Compare(Object a, Object b)
   at System.Collections.Generic.ObjectComparer`1.Compare(T x, T y)
   at System.Collections.Generic.ArraySortHelper`1.InsertionSort(T[] keys, Int32 lo, Int32 hi, IComparer`1 comparer)
   at System.Collections.Generic.ArraySortHelper`1.IntroSort(T[] keys, Int32 lo, Int32 hi, Int32 depthLimit, IComparer`1 comparer)
   at System.Collections.Generic.ArraySortHelper`1.IntrospectiveSort(T[] keys, Int32 left, Int32 length, IComparer`1 comparer)
   at System.Collections.Generic.ArraySortHelper`1.Sort(T[] keys, Int32 index, Int32 length, IComparer`1 comparer)
[System.InvalidOperationException: Failed to compare two elements in the array.]
   at System.Collections.Generic.ArraySortHelper`1.Sort(T[] keys, Int32 index, Int32 length, IComparer`1 comparer)
   at System.Array.Sort[T](T[] array, Int32 index, Int32 length, IComparer`1 comparer)
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.Sort(Int32 index, Int32 count, IComparer`1 comparer)
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.Sort()
   at Example.Main() :line 49
```

What is the reason why C# compiler allow this code to compile?

note: I hope it is clear that I am not asking how to fix my code, it is trivial, I am asking about why this buggy code is compiling.

Comment: Well, what if you make the class implement `IComparable` at runtime using reflection?

Comment: can we see your [sscce](http://sscce.org/)?

Comment: Why does .NET allow this to compile:  1 / 0?   I feel at some point you have to expect the developer to work within the constraints of the architecture.

Comment: The C# compiler has hardly any built-in knowledge of classes of the .NET Framework. I'm guessing that it knows nothing about `List<T>` or `ObjectComparer<T>`, let alone that one will fail if a constraint of the other isn't met.

Comment: by this logic, any method call that might possibly throw an exception shouldn't compile..? compile-time and run time checks are different things.

Comment: A language that cannot express the notion of dynamic typing cannot be successful.  Having to write code that uses a dbase is the standard example.  The most popular language in the world uses dynamic typing, its name shall not be mentioned.  In the .NET world, VB.NET always had that feature built-in.  C# made it easier yet at version 4 with the *dynamic* keyword.

Answer (score 2):

You can provide a self written comparer by implementing the `IComparer` interface. And when you don't, it will look for `Comparer<T>.Default` to get one. So technically it can be fine to call `Sort()` on a list where `Icomparable` isn't implemented by the objects, because `Comparer<T>.Default` will be used then. This means you can call `Sort()` on any list without the restriction that the values must implement `IComparable`. But this also means you cannot check at compile time if there will be a comparer available at `Comparer<T>.Default` at the time when it is is used internally by the `Sort()` source code.